# Como unir Android Studio Con unity

Tags: android-studio

¿Con un compañero estamos intentando crear una apicacion  de realidad aumentada pero uniendo  Android studio y unity utilizando vuforia ayuda.?

Comment: Hola Andres!, te saludo y te doy la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, por lo tanto te sugiero modificar tu pregunta, saludos!